# Problem with ManyToMany relations in spring data. It changed my table

Tags: java, sql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, h2

I had a db with tables SPEC and PARTS.Also I had a table for MANY TO MANY relations. In my project I used spring jdbs template and all works good. Then I decide to change jdbc on SPring data jpa.
My Entities:

```
  @Entity
@Table(name = "PARTS")
public class PartsJpa {
    @Id
    private int id;
    @Column(name = "NAME")
    private String name;
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "ID_EXPORT", unique = false, nullable = false, updatable = true)
    private ExportJpa exportJpa;
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "ID_TYPE", unique = false, nullable = false, updatable = true)
    private TypesJpa typesJpa;

    @Column(name = "DESCRIPTION")
    private String description;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name="SPEC_PARTS",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="ID_SPEC", referencedColumnName="id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="ID_PARTS", referencedColumnName="id")
    )
    private Set<SpecJpa> specJpa;
////////
}
```

And Spec:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "SPEC")
public class SpecJpa {
    @Id
    private int id;
    @Column(name = "NAME")
    private String name;
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "Creator_ID", unique = false, nullable = false, updatable = true)
    private UsersJpa usersJpa;
    @Column(name = "DESCRIPTION")
    private String description;


    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name="SPEC_PARTS",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="ID_SPEC", referencedColumnName="id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="ID_PARTS", referencedColumnName="id")
    )
    private Set<PartsJpa> partsJpa;
////////////////
}
```

I don't show getters and setters.
It works, but when I start a programm, something in my table was changed and now I can't add in table spec_parts values like(1,3)(1,2). 
Mistake: 
***FK_123: PUBLIC.SPEC_PARTS FOREIGN KEY(ID_PARTS) REFERENCES PUBLIC.SPEC(ID) (3)" Referential integrity constraint violation: "FK_123: PUBLIC.SPEC_PARTS FOREIGN KEY(ID_PARTS) REFERENCES PUBLIC.SPEC(ID) (3)"; SQL statement: INSERT INTO "PUBLIC"."SPEC_PARTS"("ID_SPEC","ID_PARTS")VALUES(?,?)***

Maybe I have mistake with creating relations between spec and parts? What problem it can be?

data in spec

```
ID      NAME    CREATOR_ID      DESCRIPTION     CHANGER_ID  
1       pc            1         description     1
2       pc2           2         description2    2
```

data in parts

```
ID ▼    NAME    ID_EXPORT   ID_TYPE     DESCRIPTION  
1   intel core i5   1        1           d1
2   intel core i7   1        1           d2
3   ddr3            2        2           d3
4   ddr4            2        2           d4
5    asus           3        3           d5
```

data in spec_parts now:

```
ID_SPEC     ID_PARTS  
1           1
2           2
```

so I can't add 1,3 or 2,4

---

I find a problem, spring date change something and now in table SPEC_PARTS ID_SPEC mapping on PARTS.ID. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using `ManyToMany` relation, there is a mapping table created named `SPEC_PARTS` which have referenced columns `ID_SPEC` and `ID_PARTS`.These columns value come from `SPEC.ID` and `PARTS.ID`. So you can't insert in `SPEC_PARTS` without creating referenced value because you are trying to do foreign key constraint violation.

Suppose if there is a row in `SPEC` with `id` value `1` and there is a row in `PARTS` with `id` value `2`. Then you can insert in `SPEC_PARTS` with value like (1,2).

So, first, add data in `SPEC` and `PARTS` then map them in `SPEC_PARTS`.
And you can remove `@JoinTable` from one side, you don't need to define it both side.

**Update:**

Problem is SpecJpa class relation. Here you are using `SPEC_PARTS.ID_SPEC` as foriegn key for `PARTS.ID` and `SPEC_PARTS.ID_PARTS` as foriegn key for `SPEC.ID` which is fully reversed what you do in PartsJpa class.

```
@JoinTable(name="SPEC_PARTS",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="ID_SPEC", referencedColumnName="id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="ID_PARTS", referencedColumnName="id")
    )
```

That's why this error say

```
SPEC_PARTS FOREIGN KEY(ID_PARTS) REFERENCES PUBLIC.SPEC(ID) (3)";
```

There is no `SPEC.ID` value 3 exist in the database.

Solution:
Remove `@JoinTable` from SpecJpa class as you don't need to specify both side.
And remove the wrong relation of the foreign key from database also.

Comment: I understand, but early in table spec_parts i can add values (1,2) (1,3) (1,4), (2,1), (2,5). But now I can only (1,2) (2, 3), but I can not add yet one like (1,3) or (2,4)

Comment: Can you add current data on SPEC and PARTS table which is related with your question.